# Simplify the expression: $A'BC' + A'BC + AB'C + ABC' + ABC$

Tags: boolean-algebra

The online calculator(not posting the name because I don't know if its's allowed) is giving me a different result and I can't find what I'm doing wrong:

Mine:

$A'BC' + A'BC + AB'C + ABC' + ABC=
BC'(A'+A) + BC(A' + A) + AB'C=
BC' + BC + AB'C=
B(C' + C) + AB'C=
B + AB'C$

The calculator's:

$=AC + BC' + BA'$

Comment: Could you explain what $A$, $A'$, etc. are? Posting the name of your calculator is fine.

Comment: @preferred_anon It's boolean algebra, that's why i tagged it. A is just a variable for 0/1 and A' is basically not(A). The website i used is: boolean-algebra.com

Comment: You are both right. $BC' + BA' + AC = BC' + BA' + ABC + AB'C = B + AB'C$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two answers are equivalent:

$$\begin{align*}
AC+BC'+BA'&=AC+B(A'+C')\\
&=AC+B(AC)'\\
&=AC(B+B')+B(AC)'\\
&=ACB+ACB'+B(AC)'\\
&=B\big(AC+(AC)'\big)+AB'C\\
&=B+AB'C
\end{align*}$$